Jemalloc with java on Mac
trying to load jemalloc for java program to find native memory leak ,but unable to get it worked. Steps performed so far
versions :  Mac OS 14.3 , JDK 11 , jemalloc - 5.3.0
1.Installed jemalloc via brew
2.set env variable LD_PRELOAD= {path_to_lib}/libjemalloc.2.dylib (tried libjemalloc.dylib also )
3.and this also MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:10,lg_prof_sample:17,prof_prefix:my_path
and I am expecting at least some logs which shows me if this is working but neither seeing logs nor seeing jeprof.**.heap
I even ran normal program with LD_PRELOAD= {path_to_lib}/libjemalloc.2.dylib MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:10,lg_prof_sample:17,prof_prefix:my_path java test.jar
my java program is simply leaking native memory via Bytebuffer.allocateDirect() and want to check this via jemalloc.
Questions :

jemalloc works on Mac OS? Do I need to install and build myself instead of brew ?
Any other config is missing ?


What does it mean "unable to get it worked"? Are there errors?

ByteBuffer.allocateDirect registers the memory with a cleaner to be cleaned up when the ByteBuffer instance is GCd. If this memory is being leaked, it would be because the ByteBuffer instances itself are being leaked. That is not something which native memory tracking would be able to detect.

I mean I just thought it might leak memory but main question is why jemalloc is not working as expected , is my config is incorrect ?

@aled , so as per internet and stackoverflow answers  , I am supposed to see jeprof.*.heap files in my local folder where I am running program

LD_PRELOAD is Linux-specific.
On macOS, there is a different mechanism for preloading shared libraries. Look for DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES. Note this may not work with SIP (System Integrity Protection) enabled.

what about MALLOC_CONF ? for Mac is there any specific option for this as well ? I see mallocctl and _RJEM_MALLOC_CONF but both are not working

and I think DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is working because with DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES instead of LD_PRELOAD , I am seeing at least this now ( with MALLOC_CONF env variable )
: Invalid conf pair: prof:true
: Invalid conf pair: lg_prof_interval:10
: Invalid conf pair: lg_prof_sample:17
: Invalid conf pair: prof_prefix:test
so I think LD_Preload problem solved , just Malloc_conf is pending

@prasannajoshi You have probably installed a version of jemalloc without profiling feature. Rebuild jemalloc from sources with --enable-prof option.
